# Can anyone shorten this excel formula

Tags: excel

I'm working on a formula to compare 2 text values and display the "highest Priority"
I have created the formula below and it works great (I have messed with the formatting for ease of  reading)

My issue is that I'm trying to write this into a macro (using recorder) and I would rather have this shorter and easier to read. 
My macro is throwing some errors which I'm certain has to do with the length.

```
        =IFERROR(
    IF([@[Standardised Priority]]="A","A",IF([@Priority]="Blocker","A",
    IF([@[Standardised Priority]]="B","B",IF([@Priority]="Critical","B",
    IF([@[Standardised Priority]]="C","C",IF([@Priority]="Major","C",
    IF([@[Standardised Priority]]="D","D",IF([@Priority]="Minor","D",
    IF([@[Standardised Priority]]="E","E",IF([@Priority]="Triv","E",
    "UNCLASSIFIED")))))))))),"UNCLASSIFIED")
```

I have 3 columns (1, 2, 3)
Column 1 can have A,B,C,D,E (A = highest/E= Lowest)
Column 2 can have "Blocker","Critical","Major","Minor","Trivial" (Blocker = Highest/Trivial = Lowest)
Column 3 displays the Highest Priority

Comment: Can you add the logic you are using in words? That usually helps you figure out what conditions can be clubbed together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a vlookup for this.

Create a vlookup table somewhere (on another sheet?) as follows:

```
       A       |    B
1   Text value | VLOOKUP Value
2   Blocker    |    A
3   Critical   |    B
```

You can then use a vlookup as follows, assuming all other values other than [ABCDE] in the column "Standardized priority" are empty (""):

```
IF([@[Standardised Priority]]<>"";[@[Standardised Priority]];VLOOKUP([@Priority];$A$3:$B$4;2;FALSE))
```

Definitely still not pretty, but it's shorter. Try making a sheet name config or so and create the vlookup table as a named Excel table in order to allow it to add new rows dynamically (be sure to edit the formula above to point to the new table instead of $A$2:$A$3)